# Android Virtual Device Manager - "No. of emulated web cameras"?

Tags: android, android-emulator

In Android Emulator, `Window->AVD Manager->Hardware` has an option `Number of emulated web cameras`.

1) What exactly is this option supposed to do when the Android Emulator Documentation explicitly states *No support for USB connections* in the *Emulator Limitations* section (as of Jul 12 2012).

2) Is this limitation applicable for JNI programs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the *number of emulated web cameras* refers to the number of front facing cameras of the phone.